# Exchange Public Folder - Cannot open mailbox

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server, exchange-server-2013, public-folders

We have a Exchange 2013 Version 15.0 (Build 1293.2) running OnPremise in Hybrid with Office365. All our Mailbox are migrated to Exchange online except PublicFolder.
On Preparing the environment to migrate the PublicFolder we accidently deleted them. ([Blogpost](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/undocumentedfeatures/2017/04/08/migrating-hybrid-public-folders-to-office-365/))
The PublicFolder was only disconnected so we connected it to a new AD-User [Blogpost](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2013/10/28/recovering-public-folder-information-in-exchange-2013-part-2/).

But since it was the primary hierachy, the recovered PF was now secondary. I fixed this with ADSIedit and changed the msExchDefaultPublicFolderMailbox. But got no luck access it.

OnPremise with Powershell *Get-PublicFolder* I get the following:

```
Cannot open mailbox /o=<DOMAIN>/ou=Exchange Administrative Group
(FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Configuration/cn=Servers/cn=<SERVER>/cn=Microsoft System Attendant.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-PublicFolder], StoragePermanentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=<SERVER>,RequestId=a0513385-ff9e-472f-a21a-719fbcac071e,TimeStamp=15.11.2017 07:20:42] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-StoragePermanentException] 4E3BE011,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.MapiTasks.
GetPublicFolder
+ PSComputerName        : SERVER.DOMAIN.local
```

I made a second empty PublicFolder (named **test**) and changed the msExchDefaultPublicFolderMailbox to set it as primary. Now the *Get-PublicFolder* worked. But after 5 to 15 minutes the PublicFolder wasn't available again. Another *Get-PublicFolder* got me the same message as above.
The same thin happened if I changed it back to my reconnected PF (**PFU01**).

With Get-Mailbox -PublicFolder I can see both PublicFolders:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>get-Mailbox -PublicFolder

Name                      Alias                ServerName        ProhibitSendQuota
----                      -----                ----------       -----------------
PFU01                     PFU01                <servername>  Unlimited
test                      test                 <servername>  Unlimited
```

What I checked:

ADSIEdit:

- "Microsoft System Attendant" got no value in "homeMDB". ([Article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/a0bce415-6cbb-40ee-99b4-5d3709a31d87/cannot-open-mailbox-cnmicrosoft-system-attendant?forum=exchangesvrgeneral))
- Change of msExchDefaultPublicFolderMailbox attribute to a new empty PF. ([Article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bc0dd7f6-a832-4980-b6af-93e175dfa14c/getpublicfolder-unable-to-open-system-attendant-mailbox?forum=Exch2016Adm))

PowerShell:

- test-mapiconnectivity (Result: Success)

Is there any other stuff I can check via ADSIEdit that could be incorrect?

Greetings,
Dominic